# Math.random() and .replace() cross-browser

Tags: javascript, random, cross-browser

I recently wrote the code to generate 10 characters randomly. `Math.random()` gives a decimal to `toString(36)` and all the numbers will be replaced.

```
Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g,'').substr(1,10);
```

Does anybody have a hint why Firefox (47.0) and Chrome (51) don't handle this equally?

Chrome tests:

```
Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g,'').substr(1,10);
"spkcirhyzb"
"gcqbrmulxe"
"sallvbzqbk"
"pcdcufhqet"
"knfffqsytm"
```

Firefox tests:

```
Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g,'').substr(1,10);
"zxntpvn"
"hebfyxlt"
"zclj"
"ormtqw"
"cfbsnye"
```

Live version:

```js
for (var n = 0; n < 5; ++n) {
  console.log(Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g,'').substr(1,10));
}
```

**UPDATE (string average):**

```js
var test;
  var count = 0;
  for (var n = 0; n < 1000; ++n) {
      test = Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g,'').substr(1,10);
      count += test.length;
  }
  console.log(count);
  console.log(count/1000);
```

My results:

Chrome - 9.999

Firefox - 6.794

Comment: Just conceptually... you can never guarantee the length of the resulting string, since the amount of a-z characters in the string is entirely random.

Comment: @deceze thats right, but see the update above, the two browsers handle this enormeours different

Comment: Yes, that *compounds* the problem, and it's a valid question why `Number.toString` behaves differently. I'm just pointing out that you shouldn't be using this algorithm in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Chrome's implementation of `Number#toString(36)` outputs more digits than Firefox's. Consider the number `0.9112907907957448`:

```
Chrome:  0.wt16lcd3ae3m96qx2a3v7vi
Firefox: 0.wt16lcd3ae
```

You can try it here:

```js
console.log((0.9112907907957448).toString(36));
```

The [spec says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-number.prototype.tostring) the algorithm can be implementation-dependent, it just has to be a "generalization" of [ToString Applied To Number Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type). Apparently the V8 team (Chrome's JavaScript engine) and the SpiderMonkey team (Firefox's) differ in their interpretations.

The rules for converting IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point ("double") numbers to strings are complex, because doubles routinely do not *precisely* store the value that we think of them as storing. For instance, `0.1` is not really `0.1` (which leads to the famous `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3` issue). It's **really, really close** to `0.1`, but it isn't `0.1`. So in theory, `(0.1).toString()` should output `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` (I *think* that's the right value). In general, though, algorithms that create strings for these values work to the rule that they only output enough digits that if you took that string and converted it back to a floating-point double, you'd get the same floating-point double. That is, even though `0.1` isn't **exactly** `0.1`, it's all the digits you need to get back to the original double value that's very nearly `0.1`. Apparently Chrome's implementation of `toString` in base 36 outputs more digits than that, probably in accordance with "NOTE 2" on the second link above, but I'm not an expert.

The technique is fundamentally flawed in any case: You're taking a string with a near-purely random series of letters and digits and removing the digits, then expecting to get at least ten remaining characters. There's no way to be sure that's actually going to be true, not even on Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working solution for your initial question on generating a random string of 10 characters.

As T. J Crowder has pointed out, your solution won't work in any browser as you are expecting it to work.

```js
var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var str = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    str += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
}
                       
console.log(str);
```

Comment: thanks a lot! one thing you are missing is a pair of brackets `str += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * (chars.length -1))];` since the substraction should be taken first

Comment: You shouldn't have that -1 in there

Comment: @Kruga you are right, `Math.random()` returns a number between `[0,1)`